# How to add the previously present value of array and then apply splice method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add the already present value of array of particular index and then  apply slpice method on it. I am using chart js to show the total amount of transaction for each month.

Below is a sample array

```
var result = ['0','50','0'];
```

Above i want to add and replace the `result[1]` with `100`

so my sample expected output should be
`var result = ['0','150','0'];`

How can i achive this?

More detail code is below

```
    var result = ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'];

    const allMoth = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/sales-overview/",
            success: function(data) {
                for( var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
                    let tansactionMonth = data[i].createdAt
                    let monthInNumber = tansactionMonth.slice(5, 7)
                    let amount = 0;
                    
                    for( var j = 0; j<= 12; j++) {
                        if(j ==  monthInNumber) {
                            console.log("hello" + result[j])
                            totalAmount = Number(result[j]) + Number(data[i].cartTotal);
                            result.splice(j-1, 1, totalAmount);
                        }   
                    }
                }   
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    })
```

Here

```
                     for( var j = 0; j<= 12; j++) {
                        if(j ==  monthInNumber) {
                            console.log("hello" + result[j])
                            totalAmount = Number(result[j]) + Number(data[i].cartTotal);
                            result.splice(j-1, 1, totalAmount);
                        }   
                    }
```

I have used some logic but it is giving me the latest updated value but not adding the old value.
If you want me to modify the code with coplete data set and chart js code then please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show more code .

Comment: Thank you swati. Actually i fixed it. i changed ```totalAmount = Number(result[j]) + Number(data[i].cartTotal);``` to ``` totalAmount = Number(result[j-1]) + Number(data[i].cartTotal); ```